# How to sort xml by node value in python

Tags: python, xml, sorting

I'm running on Ubuntu 18.04.  A Python 2 or 3 solution would be preferred.  I've got xml structured like so:

```
<Records>
  <Record>
    <recID>123</recID>
    <tstamp>2018-12-31T23:59:42.38Z</tstamp>
  </Record>
  <Record>
    <recID>456</recID>
    <tstamp>2018-10-10T12:03:02.28Z</tstamp>
  </Record>
  <Record>
    <recID>789</recID>
    <tstamp>2018-11-11T13:50:00.00Z</tstamp>
  </Record>
</Records>
```

But I've got a lot of it, a single 10GB file worth.  I'm looking for the most efficient way to sort the records on `tstamp`, such that the output would look like this:

```
<Records>
  <Record>
    <recID>456</recID>
    <tstamp>2018-10-10T12:03:02.28Z</tstamp>
  </Record>
  <Record>
    <recID>789</recID>
    <tstamp>2018-11-11T13:50:00.00Z</tstamp>
  </Record>
  <Record>
    <recID>123</recID>
    <tstamp>2018-12-31T23:59:42.38Z</tstamp>
  </Record>
</Records>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what did you try? do you want to create a new file that is sorted?

Comment: Do you have a single 10 GB XML file?

Comment: Yes, I have a single 10GB xml file.

Answer (score 1):

Below is a code that sort the records by 'tstamp'

```py
import datetime
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml = '''<Records>
  <Record>
    <recID>123</recID>
    <tstamp>2018-12-31T23:59:42.38Z</tstamp>
  </Record>
  <Record>
    <recID>456</recID>
    <tstamp>2018-10-10T12:03:02.28Z</tstamp>
  </Record>
  <Record>
    <recID>99</recID>
    <tstamp>1999-11-11T13:50:00.00Z</tstamp>
  </Record>
  <Record>
    <recID>88</recID>
    <tstamp>2020-11-11T13:50:00.00Z</tstamp>
  </Record>
  <Record>
    <recID>789</recID>
    <tstamp>2018-11-11T13:50:00.00Z</tstamp>
  </Record>
   <Record>
    <recID>11</recID>
    <tstamp>2012-11-11T13:50:00.00Z</tstamp>
  </Record>
</Records>'''
root = ET.fromstring(xml)
records = root.findall('.//Record')
records = sorted(records, key=lambda r: datetime.datetime.strptime(r.find('tstamp').text[:19], '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S'))
for r in records:
    print(f'{r.find("tstamp").text} -- {r.find("recID").text}')
root = ET.Element('Records')
root.extend(records)

ET.ElementTree(root).write('c:\\temp\\output.xml')
```

output

```
1999-11-11T13:50:00.00Z -- 99
2012-11-11T13:50:00.00Z -- 11
2018-10-10T12:03:02.28Z -- 456
2018-11-11T13:50:00.00Z -- 789
2018-12-31T23:59:42.38Z -- 123
2020-11-11T13:50:00.00Z -- 88
```

Comment: Hmmm...printing on each records iteration like you have does print sorted...but when I write to file like this ```ET.ElementTree(root).write("sorted.xml")```, the xml in the output file is not sorted.  Why doesn't writing to file preserve the sort?

Comment: @SamerA. code is updated and the data is written to a file (sorted)

Comment: Interesting to see if this is feasible on a 10 GB file. I imagine this line `root.findall('.//Record')` to be a strenuous. Maybe even this: `root.extend(records)`.

Comment: I agree - the code needs lots of RAM (given the file size..)

Comment: Nice!  Just another followup observation; if the root node ```<Records>``` had namespace and attributes like this ```<Records msgVersion="RevB" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/foobar">```, something breaks.  How can I tell ElementTree a namespace to use?  I have not tried the code on a 10GB file yet, crossing my fingers...

Comment: just call the set method of the element. see https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.set (feel free to up vote if I managed to help you..)